# Flexslider JS not Loading

Tags: javascript

Using the Nexus theme, I'm getting the following error when using the theme rotater.

"The History Plugin requires Galleria version 1.2.5 or later."

Updated and its still busted.

http://www.athleteyouniversity.com/

Comment: Which module is that?

Comment: myBad. its the Galleria module

Comment: Flexslider module has one requirement, and that's the flexslider library. Your error must be coming from another module.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Note that questions like _look at my site, and tell me what is wrong_ are not acceptable for us. The question needs to be self-contained, which means it needs to be answerable without looking at any off-site resources.

Answer (score 1):

I see in your page source it says:

```
http://www.athleteyouniversity.com/sites/all/themes/nexus/sites/all/libraries/galleria/plugins/history/galleria.history.min.js?o30qzc
```

You have a `sites/all/` folder inside your theme `/nexus` folder, which is not how it's suppose to be. **The libraries folder needs to be outside of your theme folder.**

**It's suppose to be** `/sites/all/libraries/galleria/plugins/history/galleria.history.min.js`